# Stability of Mathieu's equation and parameteric resonance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, resonance, numerical-method

I am given the following equation ([Mathieu's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function)) in my subject of Numerical Analysis :

$$
\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=-\omega^2(1+\epsilon\cos(t))x
$$

I am supposed to find those frequencies $\omega$ for which the system becomes unstable. And then draw a graph of $\epsilon (<<1) $ as a function of $\omega$ pointing out regions where the solution becomes unstable. I will have to really scan different values of $\omega$ for a fixed $\epsilon$, then change $\epsilon$ and again scan $\omega$.

This all has to be solved using Runge-Kutta order 4 method. The initial values of $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$ have to be taken as some non-zero values.

I am neither a physics student, nor a mathematics student. Please explain me in layman's terms where should I search for the required frequencies.

*PS : The professor has suggested V. I. Arnold, Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, 2nd edition, Springer-Verlag, pages 113 − 120. There I came across a theorem stating : **All points on the $\omega$-axis except the integers and half integers $\omega=k/2,k=0,1,2 ....$ correspond to strongly stable systems.** I am having a little knowledge of SHM but I am not able to get the significance of $k$ here.*

**EDIT** - 
I have come to know that for the equation of the type :

$$
\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + (a-2q\cos(2t))x=0
$$

The stable and unstable regions are given by the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Not a student of mathematics, nor physics, and your professor suggests *Arnold*? He/she must be a sadist!

Comment: Not his fault. I am a computer science student, taking the course of NA offered by the Dept. of Physics.

Comment: @Gaurav I suggest you to look first in Wikipedia at the article with the [Mathieu equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function#Mathieu_equation)

Comment: In order to understand an answer to your question you must know linear algebra and differential equations. Do you?

Comment: @AliMoh : I have read the article from Wikipedia. I have basic knowledge of LA and DE. Please have a look at the EDIT done and proceed. The complete theory is not required, just the final results would suffice.